# compare structure of php arrays regardless for content

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays that i want to compare their structure  i.e, same keys.
I tried using  `array_diff_key` but the problem is that one array is defined like this:

```
    $fields = array('id' , 'site', 'placement', 'device', 'source', 'campaign', 'url', 'country', 'dof_count', 'dof_idx', 'active');
```

so when i use `var_dump()` on it i get this result:

```
{
  [0]=>
  string(2) "id"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "site"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "placement"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "device"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "source"
  [5]=>
  string(8) "campaign"
  [6]=>
  string(3) "url"
  [7]=>
  string(7) "country"
  [8]=>
  string(9) "dof_count"
  [9]=>
  string(7) "dof_idx"
  [10]=>
  string(6) "active"
}
```

and the other is created by a function and comes back like this:

```
{
  ["id"]=>
  NULL
  ["site"]=>
  NULL
  ["placement"]=>
  NULL
  ["device"]=>
  NULL
  ["source"]=>
  NULL
  ["campaign"]=>
  NULL
  ["url"]=>
  NULL
  ["country"]=>
  NULL
  ["dof_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["dof_idx"]=>
  NULL
  ["active"]=>
  NULL
}
```

so while the two arrays have the same structure, `array_diff_key` won't help. is there a way in php to compare this two array's structure while ignoring the content, which in my case it's all the null's and the one int in the second array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `array_diff` along with `array_keys` as

```
$result = array_diff($fields,array_keys($keys_array));
```

**Note : Not Tested**

Comment: This fails on multi-dimensional arrays

Answer (score 1):

I saw the other answers and for all I know they are correct. Those functions will be able to help you out.

But I couldn't understand why would you create your array like this:

```
$fields = array('id' , 'site', 'placement', 'device', 'source', 'campaign', 'url', 'country', 'dof_count', 'dof_idx', 'active');
```

If your objective was to simply verify the other array all along, then simply associatively create it:

```
<?php
        $fields = array(
            'id' => null,
            'site' => null,
            'placement' => null,
            /*...*/
            'active' => null
        );
```

But still, I don't understand your need to verify the array structure, given that it should always be the same. If you have more than one input type for the array's then you should create a field called type on all of the arrays you are going to return and "if" them from there.
Example:

```
<?php
/*This array has a type and only two indexes of data.*/
$inputArray = array(
    'type' => 'firstType',
    'data1' => 'data',
    'data2' => 'data'
);

/*This array also has a type but 6 indexes containing datas*/
$anotherInputArray = array(
    'type' => 'secondType',
    'data3' => 'data',
    'data4' => 'data',
    'data4' => 'data',
    'data4' => 'data',
    'data4' => 'data',
    'data4' => 'data'
);

treatArray($inputArray);
treatArray($anotherInputArray);

function treatArray($array){
    if($array['type']=='firstType'){
        /*Treat it in one way*/
    }elseif($array['type']=='secondType'){
        /*Or the other way*/
    }
}
```

I hope I could help, but you didn't describe the context you are working with, so I did my best to guess arround (even though it is not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

Just `array_flip` your `$field` array:

```
var_dump(array_diff_key(array_flip($fields), $array2));
```